# Change Placeholder Text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a jQuery placeholder plugin(https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder). I need to change the placeholder text with the change in dropdown menu. But it is not changing. Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
    $('#serMemdd').change(function () {
        var k = $(this).val();
        if (k == 1) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a name (Lastname, Firstname)").placeholder();
        }
        else if (k == 2) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type an ID").placeholder();
        }
        else if (k == 3) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a Location").placeholder();
        }
    });
});
```

My Html:

```
<div class="filterbox">
        <select name="ddselect" id="serMemdd">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Search by Name</option>
            <option value="2">Search by ID</option>
            <option value="3">Search by Location</option>
        </select>
        <input id="serMemtb" type="text" style="width: 490px" placeholder="Type a name    (Lastname, Firstname)" />
        <input id="seMemBut" type="button" value="Search" />
    </div>
```

Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: Can you provide your html as well?

Comment: @TimothyAaron I have provided the HTML

Comment: @Blankasaurus - BS does not have this built in. Placeholder attribute works natively in modern browsers, but there is no polyfill for IE: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2401

Answer (score 438, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('form').find("input[type=textarea], input[type=password], textarea").each(function(ev)
  {
      if(!$(this).val()) { 
     $(this).attr("placeholder", "Type your answer here");
  }
  });
});
```

Copy and paste this code in your js file, this will change all placeholder text from whole site.

Comment: You should omit the `if`-statement, as usually you want to set the placeholder no matter if the input element has a value or not. Otherwise,  no placeholder is shown if the user empties the input element.

Answer (score 102):

You can use following code to update a placeholder by id:

```
$("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a Location").val("").focus().blur();
```

Answer (score 30):

simply you can use

```
$("#yourtextboxid").attr("placeholder", "variable");
```

where, if variable is string then you can use like above, if it is variable replace it with the name like "variable" with out double quotes.

eg: `$("#youtextboxid").attr("placeholder", variable);`
it will work.

Comment: I have tested this but it seems you need to clear the value first if it was there.
__$("#youtextboxid").val("");__

Answer (score 15):

The plugin doesn't look very robust. If you call `.placeholder()` again, it creates a new `Placeholder` instance while events are still bound to the old one.

Looking at the code, it looks like you could do:

```
$("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a name (Lastname, Firstname)").blur();
```

---

**EDIT**

`placeholder` is an [HTML5 attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute), [guess who's not supporting it?](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/inputs.html)

Your plugin doesn't really seem to help you overcome the fact that IE doesn't support it, so while my solution works, your plugin doesn't. Why don't you find one that does.

Answer (score 10):

`$(this).val()` is a string.  Use `parseInt($(this).val(), 10)` or check for '1'.  The ten is to denote base 10.

```
$(function () {
    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').blur();
    $('#serMemdd').change(function () {
        var k = $(this).val();
        if (k == '1') {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a name (Lastname, Firstname)").blur();
        }
        else if (k == '2') {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type an ID").blur();
        }
        else if (k == '3') {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a Location").blur();
        }
    });
});
```

### Or

```
$(function () {
    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
    $('#serMemdd').change(function () {
        var k = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (k == 1) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a name (Lastname, Firstname)").blur();
        }
        else if (k == 2) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type an ID").blur();
        }
        else if (k == 3) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a Location").blur();
        }
    });
});
```

### Other Plugins

ori has brought to my attention that the plugin you are using does not overcome IEs HTML failure.

Try something like this:
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/input-placeholder

Comment: Note for OP: Also note that the change event is hooked to the select box, not the text input. `$('#serMemdd').change(function () {`

Comment: I think hes trying to make the placeholder text context sensitive based on the serMemdd DDL.  I dunno.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it seems like to me, but in his JS, he has the change event hooked to the textarea, which is not where it should be hooked if that is the functionality he is after.  That's why I called out a note to that change in your code, in case he wasn't aware.

Comment: Updated my answer with blur() since .placeholder() messes stuff up if you call it more than one time. You should call it in your doc.ready to set it up though.

Comment: <select name="ddselect" id="serMemdd">

Comment: I Have tried with your code, but it is not working in IE. In chrome due to HTML5 placeholder, it works fine. What happens in IE is that , on select from dropdown, placeholder becomes normal text(with prev text) and I have to remove it manually and when I click outside the textbox, the correct placeholder text appears

Comment: I think this still answers your initial question as to why the code you has wasn't being executed.  If you want IE support you will have to get a new plugin that doesn't rely on HTML5.  Sorry =(

Comment: And **if** you copied the `blur` from my answer, you should've mentioned it.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("input[type=search]").attr("placeholder","this is a test");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

working example of dynamic placeholder using Javascript and Jquery http://jsfiddle.net/ogk2L14n/1/

```
<input type="text" id="textbox">
 <select id="selection" onchange="changeplh()">
     <option>one</option>
     <option>two</option>
     <option>three</option>
    </select>

function changeplh(){
    debugger;
 var sel = document.getElementById("selection");
    var textbx = document.getElementById("textbox");
    var indexe = sel.selectedIndex;

    if(indexe == 0) { 
     $("#textbox").attr("placeholder", "age");

}
       if(indexe == 1) { 
     $("#textbox").attr("placeholder", "name");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change placeholder text using jquery

**try this**

```
$('#selector').attr("placeholder", "Type placeholder");
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input is inside the div than you can try this:

```
$('#div_id input').attr("placeholder", "placeholder text");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('#Selector_ID').attr("placeholder", "your Placeholder");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('form').find("input[type=search]").each(function(ev)
  {
     $(this).attr("placeholder", "Search Whatever you want");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving your first line to the bottom does it for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tcloninger/SEmNX/

```
$(function () {
    $('#serMemdd').change(function () {
        var k = $(this).val();
        if (k == 1) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a name (Lastname, Firstname)").placeholder();
        }
        else if (k == 2) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type an ID").placeholder();
        }
        else if (k == 3) {
            $("#serMemtb").attr("placeholder", "Type a Location").placeholder();
        }
    });
    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder();
});
```

Comment: ...well, the placeholder attribute is changing in Chrome for me anyways. When I check it in IE, the attribute is getting changed, but it's not actually displaying it. Are you sure that's a reliable plugin?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
jQuery('form').attr("placeholder","Wert eingeben");
```

but now this don't work:

```
// Prioritize "important" elements on medium.
            skel.on('+medium -medium', function() {
                jQuery.prioritize(
                    '.important\\28 medium\\29',
                    skel.breakpoint('medium').active
                );
            });
```