# Temporarily Change Placeholder in HTML for specified time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I was examining another stack overflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232810/change-placeholder-text-using-jquery) and discovered that it almost solved my issue of how to temporarily change the placeholder text of my search (input) box, but it doesn't revert the changes to the original text after a specified time. I want it so that after the highlighting has finished its 3 second (3000) appearance/fade, the placeholder text also reverts to the original.

Original placeholder was `Search By Number`

Code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("input").val() == "") {
        $("button").click(function(event) {
            $("input").attr("placeholder","Enter Account Number.");
            $("input").effect("highlight",{color:"#D46A6A"},3000);
            event.preventDefault(); 
        });
    }
});
```

I tried putting 3000 after "Enter Account Number", so that it looked like `$("input").attr("placeholder","Enter Account Number.",3000);`, but that did not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually it should look like this: http://jsbin.com/lonun/2/edit

```
$(function() { // DOM ready shorthand

  var $inp = $('#accNumber'),             // Cache your elements
      pHolder = $inp.prop('placeholder'), // Remember the default placeh.
      $btn = $('#submitNumber');          // Cache your elements


  $btn.click(function( ev ) {

      ev.preventDefault(); 

      if( !$.trim($inp.val()) ) {         // THE 'if' GOES INSIDE THE CLICK fn!
        $inp
          .val("")        // Also!: Reset value if i.e <space> was used
          .prop('placeholder', "We need it!")        // WARN USER
          .effect("highlight",{color:"#D46A6A"}, 3000, function(){
                $inp.prop('placeholder', pHolder);   // RESTORE ORIG.
          });        
      }

  });

});
```

AS you can see from the code above I used `ID` for the needed elements, so the HTML might probably look similar to:

```
<input id="accNumber" type="text" placeholder="Acc. number"> 
<button id="submitNumber">DONE</button>
```

Comment: Really picky, but you don't need to cache `$btn`, as you only use it once.

Comment: @Matt I'll use it twice, I promise `;)`

Answer (score 2):

Use animation complete callback function. Something like this

```
$("input").effect("highlight", {color:"#D46A6A"}, 3000, function() {
    $(this).attr("placeholder","Enter Account Number.");
});
```

Update by Roko C. Buljan's comment.

Comment: You can use `$(this)` inside the callback. It's faster than iterating all over *input* selectors again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setTimeout if you would like

for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("input").val() == "") {
        $("button").click(function(event) {
            var tempPlaceholder = $("input").attr("placeholder");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("input").attr("placeholder", tempPlaceholder);
            }, 3000);
            $("input").attr("placeholder","Enter Account Number.");
            $("input").effect("highlight",{color:"#D46A6A"});
            event.preventDefault(); 
        });
    }
});
```

This will reset the input's placeholder to it's original text after 3 seconds.

Comment: The second and third line make no sense to me. What's the reason for having a `click function` inside an `if $('input').val(...` Also just having `$("input")` is an issue caller.

Comment: I didnt look at his code as much as I should have, you are correct that doesnt make that much sense.  I just dropped the setTimeout where it would have belonged if the rest of the code was valid :).  Looks like that `if` could be dropped, and as you mentioned the input selector needs a class or preferably an id

Comment: Have you tested your solution? I don't think that after setting `attr` some magic should happen once the setTimeout ends. It will just blindly re-set that same `attr`.

Comment: Yes, also if you plan to reuse the same selector, might be a nice idea to cache it first.

Comment: I updated to make sure the placeholder is saved.  On the subject of the selector, while it isnt good practice to not target in a more specific manner it is what was in the code.  It could  well work on the page in question if there is only 1 input on the page.

Comment: Nice, I answered with all the needed stuff to actually make it work.