# Placeholder on item title and description

Tags: javascript, php, html

i try to add a placeholder on the title and description box.

I try this script already but its not working!

Hope someone can help me for the right way!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#title').attr("placeholder", "test");
    $('#description').attr("placeholder", "test");
  });
</script>



      <div id="item-post-title" class="item-post-title">
        <label class="control-label" for="title[<?php echo osc_current_user_locale(); ?>]" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;">
          <span class="required_fields">* </span>
          <?php _e('Title', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
          (<?php printf(__('max %s chars','ctg_housing'),$max_character_length_title); ?>) 
        </label> <span id="Tcounter"></span>
        <?php ItemForm::title_input('title',osc_current_user_locale(), osc_esc_html( ctg_housing_item_title() )); ?>
      </div>
      <div id="item-post-description" class="item-post-description">
        <label class="control-label" for="description[<?php echo osc_current_user_locale(); ?>]" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;">
          <span class="required_fields">* </span>
          <?php _e('Description', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
          (<?php printf(__('max %s chars','ctg_housing'),$max_character_length_description); ?>)
        </label> <span id="Dcounter"></span>
        <?php ItemForm::description_textarea('description',osc_current_user_locale(), osc_esc_html( ctg_housing_item_description() )); ?>
        <?php if(!osc_plugin_is_enabled('richedit/index.php')){ ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232810/change-placeholder-text-using-jquery

Comment: I do not find how to change it!

Answer (score 0):

First check your jquery libraby included or not , if not then you can add cdn jquery by

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

OR you can use js to set placholder.(for example i added below div ).

```
 document.getElementById("title").placeholder = "hello";
```

**Note: Please add js below div or in footer.**

**Example-**

```
<div id="item-post-title" class="item-post-title">
        <label class="control-label" for="title[<?php echo osc_current_user_locale(); ?>]" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;">
          <span class="required_fields">* </span>
          <?php _e('Title', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
          (<?php printf(__('max %s chars','ctg_housing'),$max_character_length_title); ?>) 
        </label> <span id="Tcounter"></span>
        <?php ItemForm::title_input('title',osc_current_user_locale(), osc_esc_html( ctg_housing_item_title() )); ?>
      </div>
      <div id="item-post-description" class="item-post-description">
        <label class="control-label" for="description[<?php echo osc_current_user_locale(); ?>]" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;">
          <span class="required_fields">* </span>
          <?php _e('Description', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
          (<?php printf(__('max %s chars','ctg_housing'),$max_character_length_description); ?>)
        </label> <span id="Dcounter"></span>
        <?php ItemForm::description_textarea('description',osc_current_user_locale(), osc_esc_html( ctg_housing_item_description() )); ?>
        <?php if(!osc_plugin_is_enabled('richedit/index.php')){ ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("title").placeholder = "hello";
</script>
```

Please check this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/889zepgf/

Comment: When i add this script only nothing happens <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("title").placeholder = "hello";
</script>

Comment: then comment your html code and create a text field like js fiddle and then check its working or not and also share html of input field from source code(browser )

Comment: i'm new in this can you explain me how?

Comment: ok no problem , first replace you div with <div id="item-post-title" class="item-post-title"><input type="text" name="title" id="title"></div> <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("title").placeholder = "hello";
</script>  and check its working or not

Comment: ok remove this and add your old code ,can you show me html of your input field from source code,  open your page in browser then press control+u a source code tab will open search for input field with title id or name and show me that html input field.

Comment: view-source:http://www.propertyadsphilippines.com/test-theme/index.php?page=item&action=item_add

Comment: see your input field id showing titleen_US and for description showing descriptionen_US, replace in jquery this id or  you can add this below div <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("titleen_US").placeholder = "hello";
document.getElementById("descriptionen_US").placeholder = "hello";
</script>

Comment: please upvote and accept my answer if its helpful for u :).

Comment: this will only work where locale is - `en_US` and not for other locales

Comment: dont worry, replace javascript code with this   <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('item-post-title').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].placeholder = "hello";
document.getElementById('item-post-description').getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].placeholder = "hello"; 
</script>  or if you using jquery then  $('#item-post-title input').attr("placeholder", "testg");  and accept answer and also upvote . :) @TusharWalzade

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code, it generates field ids dynamically as - **`titleen_US`, `descriptionen_US`** etc. Therefore **you can't access it as - `$('#title').attr("placeholder", "test");` and `$('#description').attr("placeholder", "test");` in your jQuery**.

And ***doing this is not a better solution*** -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#titleen_US').attr("placeholder", "test");
    $('#descriptionen_US').attr("placeholder", "test");
});
```

*Because*, your **`osc_current_user_locale()` will return different value as per user locale** and it will **only work where locale is - en_US** and **not for other locales** .

> So, instead of complicating things, apply ***class*** attribute to your html inputs as - **`class="title"` & `class="description"`** respectively and so your jQuery code will be -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.title').attr("placeholder", "test");
    $('.description').attr("placeholder", "test");
});
```

Comment: So, instead of complicating things, apply class attribute to your html inputs as - class="title" & class="description" respectively and so your jQuery code will be

Comment: <?php ItemForm::title_input('title',osc_current_user_locale(), osc_esc_html( ctg_housing_item_title() )); ?>

Comment: Which framework you are using? Search for - how to apply css class to input field in That* framework.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#titleen_US').attr("placeholder", "Test Title");
  });
</script>
```